Proof of equivalent definitions of injectivity
Define a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$
Then the following statements are equivalent:
i)$f$ is injective.
ii)$f^{-1}(f(A))=A,A \subset X$
iii) $f(A \cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$
Proof:
(I have edited this proof after reading the comments)
$i\rightarrow ii$
Assume that f is injective but ii doesn't hold. Then there exists a set $A$ with $f^{-1}(f(A))≠A$. Then there exists a $b \not \in A$ with $b \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. But this implies that $f(b)=f(a)$ for $a≠b,a\in A$ holds. But this contradicts the fact that f is injective.
$ii\rightarrow iii$
We have that $f^{-1}(f(A \cap B))=A \cap B=f^{-1}(f(A))\cap f^{-1}(f(B))=f^{-1}(f(A)\cap f(B))$
$iii \rightarrow i$
We want to show that $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$. Set $A=\{a\},B=\{b\}$ Then we have $f(\{a\}\cap \{b\})=f(\{a\})$ so we have $\{a\}=\{b\}$ and are done.
Does this proof work? What could be improved?

You can't choose a specific set when you are trying to prove that something holds for all sets.

Do you mean the first one? But if I assume that $i$ holds but $ii$ doesn't hold $ii$ wouldn't hold for all subsets of X. So it would also doesn't hold for this specific sets

Assuming that $ii$ doesn't hold for all sets doesn't mean that it doesn't hold for a particular set.

@JohnDouma Yes I was wrong. Thank you for pointing this out.

For $i \to ii$, you have misunderstood the claim in $(ii)$. If you assume $(ii)$ does not hold, there then exists as set $A$ such that $f^{-1}(f(A)) \ne A$, but you cannot be sure it is a singleton and certainly not for any particular arbitrary $a$. In other words, you, the prover, does not get to choose a specific $A$ for which $(ii)$ fails.
For $ii \to iii$, your proof convinces me that $f^{-1}(f(A\cap B)) = f^{-1}(f(A)) \cap f^{-1}(f(B))$, but that is not what what $iii$ claims. $iii$ makes a claim about $f(A\cap B)$ and $f(A) \cap f(B)$.
For $iii \to i$, everything looks okay, but I would explicitly point out why you are done -- since you have shown that $f(\{a\} \cap \{b\}) = f(\{a\})$ then $f(\{a\} \cap \{b\})$ is nonempty and thus $\{a\} \cap \{b\} \ne \emptyset$ so that $a = b$.
Added to More Fully Develop and Idea from Comments
I find for these sorts of problems that going back to basic set equality often helps clarify for myself why the proof works, even if there is a more streamlined "move the $f$s around version which works.
For example, I'll take $ii \to iii$: Intuitively, I know that $ii$ says that $f$ is special in that $f^{-1}$ never makes things "bigger."  Let's see how to use that:
We want to show that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap B$. Let $A,B \subseteq X$.
Let $x \in f(A \cap B)$. Then there is $a \in A\cap B$ so that $f(a) = x$. Thus, $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$. [Since I did not use any special property of $f$, this is the part that is always true for all functions -- and should make sense -- $A \cap B$ is in general "smaller" compared to $A$ or $B$ individually, but, for non-injective functions, $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ could overlap even if $A$ and $B$ do not.]
Now, let $x \in f(A) \cap f(B)$. Then, there exist $a \in A$ so that $f(a) = x$ and $b \in B$ so that $f(b) = x$. [Again, in general, if $f$ was not going to turn out to be injective, we'd be stuck!] Consider $f^{-1}(f(\{a\})) = \{a\}$, by the claim of $ii$. But then, since $f(a) = x$, we have $f^{-1}(f(\{a\})) = f^{-1}(\{x\})$. But clearly, $b$ belongs to this set as well, since $f(b) = x$. Thus, $b \in \{a\}$ and thus $a = b$. Thus, $a \in A \cap B$ and so $x = f(a) = f(A \cap B)$.
We can see that the special claim of $ii$ is what allowed us to overcome the problem that in general, $g(A) \cap g(B) \not\subseteq g(A \cap B)$ for all functions $g$, since when $g$ is not injective, $g$ can produce the same "output" value from distinct "inputs."  Yes, this proof is a lot longer but, at least for me, helps provide insight that can be hidden by shorter ones.

Would $i\rightarrow ii$ work this way? Assume that f is injective and theres a set $A$ for which $ii$ does not hold. Then there exists a $b \not \in  A$ with $f(a)=f(b), a≠b,a \in A$. But then $f$ is not injective.

And $ii \rightarrow iii$ with $f(f^{-1}(f(A\cap B)))$

For the new version of $i \to ii$: Yes, but the wording could be improved. You start with there exists $b \not\in A$ but in $f^{-1}(f(A))$ which implies the existence of an $a \in A$ so that $f(a) = f(b)$.  This proof also assumes the fact--which I don't know if you need to prove separately -- that $A \subset g^{-1}(g(A))$ for all functions $g$, since you are denying only half of the statement that 2 sets are equal. -- For your comment about $ii \to iii$: Yes, but I don't know how much detail you need to show...

... when I teach our "Intro to Proofs" course at my institution, I am very much a stickler for showing set equality explicitly or when folks want to use, for lack of a better term "algebraic manipulation" -- i.e. moving the $f$s around, whatever -- explicitly referencing the appropriate theorems/problems that say we can do this. It is hard to know here what is assumed/needs to be shown.

Yes my problem is that I'm learning this on my own and don't have anyone to talk about this so I have only mathstackexchange for those things. This is out of a book and those facts were proven in the chapter so I think I could use them. Sorry if my English is sometimes hard to understand I am not a native speaker.

No problem at all -- happy to try to help (and it is useful context that you're doing this on your own).  I will add, then, that at least for me, seeing the more baseline set equality helps me see why these statements are true. I am going to expand my previous answer with some additional details to try to describe what I mean.
